# How to get birth place in Gramps 4.2.1?

Tags: gramps, birthplace

I have a script to create a book from the database of Gramps. After an update to Gramps 4.1 (I have now 4.2.1), the place have a [hierarchical place structure](https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Hierarchical_Place_Structure). How can I retrieve the birth place now with python 3?

My legacy code was:

```
            birth = self.database.get_event_from_handle(birth_ref.ref)
            place_handle = birth.get_place_handle()
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about coding not family history or genealogy. Might be better placed on StackOverflow?

Comment: This is coding, but Gramps is one of the most popular open source genealogy programs, and Python is easy to learn.

Comment: Just because something is easy to learn doesn''t make it on-topic here. I could reach you to boil an egg in a few minutes but we wouldn't let you ask for cookery instructions here. @DougBlank

Comment: My point in ease of coding was that editing code in Gramps is about as complicated as editing a configuration file in any genealogy program. And it might make a nice example (as this short two-line code demonstrates) for people to learn that they can easily write scripts to manage their genealogical data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look up a place, given a place handle:

```
place = db.get_place_from_handle(place_handle)
print(place.name.value)
```